# Как вывести метод класса в шаблон django?

Tags: python, django, django-model

**view.py**

```
class test(ListView):
    model = TestModel
    template_name = 'test/test.html'
    context_object_name = 'test'

    def myfunc(self):
        return 'test'
```

Как вывести в шаблон html функцию myfunc?
`{{ myfunc }}` и `{{ test.myfunc }}` не работает...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933718/django-python-calling-a-model-class-function-with-an-argument-from-template

Comment: точно, template_tags, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

задачу решил, кому может пригодится

**views.py**

```
 class TestView(ListView):
        model = Test
        template_name = 'test/test.html'
        context_object_name = 'test'   
        
        def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['test_data']= 'some data'
            return context
```

**test_tags.py**

```
register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('test/test_tags.html')
def install_plugin(arg1='empty'):
    #some work...
    return {'data' : arg1}
```

**test_tags.html**

```
{{ data }}
```

**test.html**

```
{% test_tags test_data %}
```